# Android SDK 30, write to the root of external storage

Tags: android, file, media

I have a problem that I am sure I am not the only one to encounter. Today I use a file export system for my Android application. I write my export files in a folder at the same level as the system folders :

> |-Android 
> |-Documents  
> |-Music
> |-Downloads 
> |-MyApp 
> |- etc.

With the new storage system for SDK 30, I can no longer access this folder. So I am stuck in SDK 29 with the flag **"requestLegacyExternalStorage"**.

Is it possible to create a shortcut to the Android/data/com.mypackage folder to this folder at root level?

Is there a package to work around this problem? I've been looking for a solution to this problem for two years without success. I would like to keep this folder in the root, because it is easy to access especially during USB transfers.

I know the Privacy Policy, but this is for a professional App, they doesn't carry about this thing.

Comment: "I would like to keep this folder in the root" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the *user* decide where on the *user's* device (or in the *user's* cloud storage) that you should be storing the *user's* content.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes as I said my users often connect via USB to retrieve data. For me moving to the Android/data folder is not a possibility, because this folder obviously allows to separate the content between applications, but its data folder is much too complex in the hierarchy for end users. Also the USB interfacing between an Android device and a PC or Mac is not optimized. The file system is very complex just to retrieve photos from photo albums.
I understand why many people use the cloud but in my area (without internet) it is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: "For me moving to the Android/data folder is not a possibility" -- FWIW, I did not suggest that. I suggested asking the users where they wanted to you to put the content, via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I could of course ask them, but I personally think that users would be lost by this choice. I'm just disappointed that application folders are not easier to access on a PC which would avoid this root folder forcing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target SDK 30 and add MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Do note it's a dangerous permission so you'll need to request it differently, like this:

```
if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
        requestManageAllPermission();
        return;
    }
private void requestManageAllPermission() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_MANAGE_EXTERNAL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_MANAGE_EXTERNAL);
    }
}
```

And you need to handle the results in:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_MANAGE_EXTERNAL) {
        if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
            finish();
    }
}
```

REQ_MANAGE_EXTERNAL is a int constant, can be any number you want, in my case its 2296

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but the REQ_MANAGE_EXTERNAL as a value or must I import something, because the method seems deprecated with a return code ?

Comment: No, it's just a an integer constant, it can be any number you want

Comment: @lupaulus I've edited the answer to include more information