# Flutter Path_provider's getExternalStorageDirectory() returns '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myApp/files', but it is not external dir

Tags: android, flutter, storage, android-external-storage, path-provider

Path_provider's getExternalStorageDirectory() on Android returns '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myApp/files', but it is not external directory. It should return something like '/storage/emulated/0/'.

How can I get this directory without hardcoding?(Because different phones will have different directories)

I tried to add
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>`

but in anyway it returns app's directory, not root directory

Comment: That is hard to believe. Try getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).

Comment: You have no access to /storage/emulated/0 and better use /storage/emulated/0/Documents.

Comment: There is no such method for path_provider such as 'getExternalStoragePublicDirectory'

Answer (score 0):

The directory path returned by getExternalStorageDirectory() might not directly point to the root of the external storage directory due to changes in Android's storage handling in recent versions.

To access the root of the external storage directory without hardcoding the path, you can use the android.os.Environment class to get the external storage directory.

Try this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<String> getExternalStorageDirectory() async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    Directory? directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (directory != null) {
      return directory.parent!.path; // Parent directory should be the root of external storage
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

refer [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70860800/android-sdk-30-write-to-the-root-of-external-storage).

for [read](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Comment: The directory.parent.path is not root directory, for me it returns '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp' path

Comment: try path_provider_android also